# Count each array item occurrence and return result as an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, categorical-data, categorization

Any native alternatives for going from:

```
const colorArray = ['red', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'red', 'red', 'black'];
```

to:

```
Object {
  "red": 3,
  "green": 2,
  "blue": 1,
  "purple": 1,
  "black": 1
}
```

in javascript??

```js
const colorArray = ['red', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'red', 'red', 'black'];

function categorizeUnique(array) {
  const distinct_objects = {};
  const length = array.length;
  for(let i=0; i<length; i++) {
    const distinct_objects_keys = Object.keys(distinct_objects);
    const possible_index = distinct_objects_keys.indexOf(array[i]);
    if(possible_index === -1) {
      distinct_objects[array[i]] = 1;
    } else {
      distinct_objects[distinct_objects_keys[possible_index]]++;
    }
  }
  return distinct_objects;
}

const result = categorizeUnique(colorArray);
console.log(result);
```

That was my try to accomplish this but I'd like a native solution already built in.

Thanks for your precious effort and time!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) seems to be pretty close to what you're looking for:

```js
const src = ['red', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'red', 'red', 'black'],

      result = src.reduce((acc,color) => (acc[color]=(acc[color]||0)+1, acc), {})
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: didn't really understand how  (acc,color) => (acc[color]=(acc[color]||0)+1, acc)  works. Btw I have a little experience with reduce, the accumulated and current arguments. Please explain.

Comment: @Jhon : I believe, its [shortcircuit OR evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#Short-circuit_evaluation) and [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) that confuses you.

Comment: @Jhon : in a nutshell, `acc[color]||0` is evalutated as `acc[color]` or `0` if former is `undefined` (upon first time crossing each specific color); `(acc[color]=(acc[color]||0)+1, acc)` is essentially the same as `acc[color] = acc[color]||0+1; return acc`

Comment: Be careful with `comma-operator` `->` [no-sequences rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-sequences)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const colorArray = ['red', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'red', 'red', 'black'];

let colorCount = colorArray.reduce((a, c) => ({ ...a, [c]: a[c] + 1 || 1}), {} );
      
console.log(colorCount);
```

Comment: The slight problem with this approach is that it re-creates unnecessarily accumulator object upon each iteration which [may slow down](https://jsbench.me/mxkejsqpzo/1) the code when input array is large enough.